# azure-sdk-for-net throws an exception on Mac

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core

I am trying to use Azure Text analysis API SDK for dotnet ([basically this nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.TextAnalytics)). I am using Mac.

I get the following exception when I run the code (I use Mac):

> The format of value 'Darwin17.7.0DarwinKernelVersion17.7.0WedOct10230614PDT2018rootxnu-4570.71.131/RELEASE_X86_64' is invalid.

This is the code that throws an exception:

```
var serviceClientCredentials = new AzureApiKeyServiceClientCredentials("<key>");
// Throw an exception here
var client = new TextAnalyticsClient(_serviceClientCredentials);
```

ServiceClientCredentials class:

```
public class AzureApiKeyServiceClientCredentials : ServiceClientCredentials
{
    private readonly string _subscriptionKey;

    public AzureApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(string subscriptionKey)
    {
        _subscriptionKey = subscriptionKey;
    }

    public override Task ProcessHttpRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", _subscriptionKey);

        return base.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

**Source of the problem**:

After trying to understand the source code I found out that `TextAnalyticsClient` tries to set a header key/value and the value is not valid http header value (i.e. `Darwin..../RELEASE_X86_64`). More specifically, I see in the source, it's setting `OsVersion` on the header of `HttpClient` and it's not url friendly value and `HttpClient` is throwing an exception:

```
this.UpdateDefaultUserAgentList("OSVersion", this.OsVersion);
```

I created an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/5046). So, all they need to do it to fix it is to [always call `CleanUserAgentInfoEntry(_osVersion)`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/b1a8f78bdf99a84c053d0e3bee279647a71e35d7/src/SdkCommon/ClientRuntime/ClientRuntime/ServiceClient.cs#L117).

I see in their source that they are getting `OsVersion` from `new PlatformInfo();` and I am wondering is it possible to change `RuntimeInformation.OSDescription`

**Update**:
I created a [pull request](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/pull/5048) to fix the issue.

Comment: I don't get it. Surely the code you linked to _already_ always calls `CleanUserAgentInfoEntry` already. `_osVersion` is a private field: if it's not set, that code sets it and cleans it. Under what circumstances could it **not** be cleaned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the issue, [thanks to @shahabhijeet](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/5046#issuecomment-440854614). I installed the latest version of `Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime` and it solved the problem.

GitHub issue thread: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/5046